# Create an EBS volume using AWS SDK for PHP 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an EBS storage and connect it to existing EC2 instance.

However I am unable to find any PHP code sample here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find that EBS management via API is part of the EC2 namespace.

Specifically:

1. Create volume: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_createVolume
2. Attach volume to instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_attachVolume

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW the new API doesn't have much code samples. Is there a useful resource to get them

Comment: I would start with the quickstart: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html. The api methods are usually pretty simple, and just take an array of args. So once you've setup your $aws object (with api keys, etc) you should be able to do something like $result = $aws->createVolume(array('Size' => 100, 'AvailabilityZone' => 'azname')); Then $result['VolumeId'] should have your VolumeID, which you can use to go attach it using attachVolume().

Comment: There are not samples for every method and service, but the conventions in the API docs are followed for everything. Checkout the S3 and DynamoDB guides for examples, and then apply the same principles to EC2 using the API docs. You can also checkout the EC2 integration tests: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/master/tests/Aws/Tests/Ec2/Integration